# Icon for UILocalNotification in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

How to set icon images(except application icon image) to `UILocalNotification` in Objective-c. I tried some code to set image by setting the alertLaunchImage property. But it does not change the icon.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: while the notification receives? when you try to display the image on the notification screen? are you trying this scenorio

Answer (score 1):

It has to be a string of filename of an image file present in the app's bundle.
(Note: It's **name** of the image, *not* an `UIImage` object)

The code below worked just fine for me:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertLaunchImage = @"icon.png";
// If you do not set the image, then it shows the app's default icon here
```

From the documentation:

> Composing the Alert alertBody  Property alertAction  Property
>   alertTitle  Property hasAction  Property alertLaunchImage  Property
>   Identifies the image used as the launch image when the user taps (or
>   slides) the action button (or slider).
>
> **Declaration** *OBJECTIVE-C* `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *alertLaunchImage` 
>   **Discussion** The string is a filename of an image file in the app bundle. This image is a launching image specified for a
>   given notification; when the user taps the action button (for example,
>   “View”) or moves the action slider, the image is used in place of the
>   default launching image. If the value of this property is nil (the
>   default), the system either uses the previous snapshot, uses the image
>   identified by the UILaunchImageFile key in the app’s Info.plist file,
>   or falls back to Default.png.
>
> The value of this key has the exact same semantics as
>   UILaunchImageFile. For more about this key, see the Information
>   Property List Key Reference.
>
> **Availability** Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

*([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertLaunchImage))*